# The etymologies behind certain topologies on the category of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, ho.history-overview, grothendieck-topology

Certain topologies on the category of schemes (or perhaps certain appropriate subcategories thereof) are named rather aptly, e.g. Zariski, étale, fppf, fpqc, syntomic, smooth, v(aluation), etc., but what about the more exotic ones like the h-topology or the arc topology ? What are their stories ?

Comment: The h-topology was introduced by Voevodsky in 1990s. I suspect "h" stands for homotopy, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: The etymology of 'syntomic' is elegant, but not exactly self-explanatory, except to speakers of ancient Greek!

Comment: According to the paper introducing the arc topology, "arc" was chosen by analogy between rank 1 valuations and arcs. I guess they're both segments of curves.

Comment: In general, your best hope for questions of this type is to look at the paper introducing the term.